# Derivative of a matrix?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

The problem states that $f : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$ is a linear map and asks for the derivative of $f$. This linear map sounds like it's a matrix, but differentiating a matrix doesn't make sense to me. Is it something else?

Comment: do you know what the definition of a differentiable function is?

Comment: I think so. If the partial derivatives of the function exist and if the function is continuous

Comment: not quite. You need to really dive into understanding the definition before you can answer this question. Consult your notes or any source online.

Comment: It says that a function is differentiable if the derivative exists. So if the derivative exists, then the partial derivatives exist and the function must be smooth which includes continuity. What other ways are there to define differentiability?

Comment: you state a consequence of differentiability (continuity etc.) and confuse it with differentiability.

Comment: Is there a definition for a linear map $f : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R^m$?

Comment: Ok, I think the definition of differentiability is $lim_{\textbf{x} \rightarrow \textbf{x}_0} \frac{||f(\textbf{x}) - f(\textbf{x}_0) - \textbf{T(x-x_0)}||}{||\textbf{x-x_0}||} = 0$ where $\textbf{T = Df(x_0)}$ is the $mxn$ matrix with matrix elements $\delta f_i / \delta x_j$ evaluated at $\textbf{x_0}$ and $\textbf{T(x-x_0)}$ means the product of $\textbf{T}$ with $\textbf{x - x0}$ (regarded as a column matrix). $\textbf{T}$ is the derivative of $f$ at $\textbf{x_0}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the definition of differentiability, $T$ is only required to be linear. It is then a consequence that if the limit you mention is indeed $0$, then $T$ is unique and can be expressed using the partial derivatives. But you don't actually need that to solve your problem. Think of what the limit tells you. It says that locally the function $f$ is well approximated by the linear map $T$. Now, if $f$ is already linear, what would be a better approximation to it than $f$ itself? So, just show that if you plug in $T=f$ into the limit then the limit does evaluate to $0$. You just need to use some properties of linearity and the denominator will just die.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the case of differentiating a matrix (which, BTW, would make perfect sense). The problem is probably asking you to find partial derivatives $\partial f_i/\partial x_j$.

Comment: Oh, okay. So the derivative itself will be an $i × j$ matrix? Does it make a difference that the question states that $f$ is a linear map?

Comment: How would you differentiate a matrix?

Comment: @user130018 if the function is differentiable, then it is approximated by a linear function (this is the meaning of differentiability, but you should go and check the details). The linear function approximating your function will be very closely related to the function itself, since it is already linear. Perhaps you were only given the notion of partial derivatives, in which case you should complement that with a better understanding of the total differential mapping.

Comment: also note that the word 'derivative' is not quite used in the context of functions of several variables. Such a function simply does not have a derivative function.